# AES Java Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am developing an application in java for a mobile platform. The program uses data from a Windows C# application which encrypts passwords in an online database which the mobile app will use.

The mobile app needs to connect to the database and retrieve the encrypted string from the database and decrypt it.

I have the decryption working fine using the following code

```
public String decrypt(String encryptedPassword)
    {
        String plainPassword = "";
        try
        {
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo".getBytes("US-ASCII"), "AES");

            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("ryojvlzmdalyglrj".getBytes("US_ASCII"));

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

            byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedPassword.getBytes()));
            plainPassword = new String(encoded);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Decryption Error", ex.toString());
        }

        return plainPassword;
    }
```

The decryption works absolutely fine so I have used the same code from the decryption for the encryption but changed the cipher mode from decrypt to encrypt. However, when I print to the console the encrypted password it prints a load of rubbish which shows no resemblance the string that should be stored in the database.

I have used the following code in order to do the encryption

```
public String encrypt(String plainPasword)
    {
        String password = "";
        try
        {
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo".getBytes("US-ASCII"), "AES");

            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("ryojvlzmdalyglrj".getBytes("US_ASCII"));

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

            byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(plainPasword.getBytes());
            password = new String(encoded);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Encryption Error", ex.toString());
        }
        return password;
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: why are you encrypting passwords?! please, use hashes of salted passwords..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the decryption function you are calling

```
byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedPassword.getBytes()));
```

so you are converting ASCII bytes to Base64 bytes, then decrypting them.

Wouldn't you do the same in the reverse, when you actually call only

```
byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(plainPasword.getBytes());
```

You also are creating new String() from byte[] array without specifying encoding, that uses platform's default encoding, not ASCII. That might break stuff too.

If you look at the bytes returned by cipher.doFinal() that's supposed to be gibberish, don't they have any resemblance to the expected data?

Comment: Beat me to it! Was just going to say the same thing :)
I will also ask why is the OP doing this himself. Unless you are really memory constrained, there are some good libraries out there that already handle all the boilerplate code like this for you.

Comment: I've got a feeling I might be doing something stupid here but it goes. I changed the line you mentioned to byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(Base64.encodeBase64(plainPasword.getBytes())); but its still outputting rubbish that doesn't resemble anything that c# creates

Comment: If your decryption goes like string->string to bytes->decodeBase64->decrypt, then your encryption must go in the exact reverse: encrypt bytes->encodeBase64->string from bytes

Comment: it's like decrypt(base64decode(bytes(input_string))) for decryption, and string(base64encode(encrypt(bytes))) for encryption; the base64 and encryption must be reversed

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for your help, i've got it working now. Again thank you.